# Is there a way to interrupt text generation in an transformers LLM call?

Tags: python, streamlit, large-language-model

I'm creating a RAG chatbot that uses the langchain and transformers libraries to generate responses to user queries using an LLM plugged into a vector index. The chatbot will live in a streamlit interface.

I want to implement a way for the user to interrupt the LLM's `generate()` function if the output is taking too long, seems to be incorrect, etc. I've explored using separate threads/processes but haven't had much luck - does anyone have any ideas?

I've tried using threads but couldn't figure out how to kill them with a certain trigger event (e.g., streamlit button). I also tried running the generation in a separate subprocess but it seemed to require loading the LLM separately (which doesn't seem memory efficient.) Let me know if I'm missing anything!